# How to update AmountDue value by InvoiceId in XERO API using C#

Tags: c#, xero-api

I am getting the list of Invoice details by Invoice Id.

Now i want to update AmountDue by respective Invoice Id.
i tried by below code:

ByInvoiceId.AmountDue = Convert.ToDecimal(100.00);
public_app_api.Invoices.Update(ByInvoiceId);

but..Error as
"A validation exception occurred"

What's the reason behind and How to solve this?

Comment: I think you may have forgotten to accept answers on all of your previous questions - https://stackoverflow.com/users/8757315/muttu-b-c .

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways to change the amount due on an invoice, however changing the value of the property directly is not one of them.

The amount due on an invoice is driven by the totals of the line items on the invoice minus the total of payments and allocated credit. One way to change the amount due is to change the values of your line items or add/remove some line items. You won't be able to change the invoice if it has been paid/partially paid.

Another way you could change the amount due on an invoice is to add a payment against the invoice or allocate credit from a credit note, prepayment, or overpayment to the invoice

Answer (score 2):

In addition to MJMortimer's answer.
You can't change the line amounts on an AUTHORISED invoice via the c# API. You have to VOID the invoice and create a new one. You can however update DRAFT and SUBMITTED ones by updating the line items.
EDIT: Here is some code to help you. This is create invoice code, but amending one is essentially the same.

```
    public XeroTransferResult CreateInvoices(IEnumerable<InvoiceModel> invoices, string user, string status)
    {
        _user = XeroApiHelper.User(user);

        var invoicestatus = InvoiceStatus.Draft;
        if (status == "SUBMITTED")
        {
            invoicestatus = InvoiceStatus.Submitted;
        }
        else if (status == "AUTHORISED")
        {
            invoicestatus = InvoiceStatus.Authorised;
        }
        var api = XeroApiHelper.CoreApi();
        var xinvs = new List<Invoice>();
        foreach (var inv in invoices)
        {
            var items = new List<LineItem>();
            foreach (var line in inv.Lines)
            {
                decimal discount = 0;
                if (line.PriceBeforeDiscount != line.Price)
                {
                    discount = (decimal)(1 - line.Price / line.PriceBeforeDiscount) * 100;
                }
                items.Add(new LineItem
                {
                    AccountCode = line.AccountCode,
                    Description = line.PublicationName != "N/A" ? line.PublicationName + " - " + line.Description : line.Description,
                    TaxAmount = (decimal)line.TaxAmount,
                    Quantity = 1,
                    UnitAmount = (decimal)line.PriceBeforeDiscount,
                    DiscountRate = discount,
                    TaxType = line.XeroCode,
                    ItemCode = line.ItemCode
                });
            }
            var person = inv.Company.People.FirstOrDefault(p => p.IsAccountContact);
            if (person == null)
            {
                person = inv.Company.People.FirstOrDefault(p => p.IsPrimaryContact);
            }
            var ninv = new Invoice
            {
                Number = inv.ClientInvoiceId,
                Type = InvoiceType.AccountsReceivable,
                Status = invoicestatus,
                Reference = inv.Reference,
                Contact = new Contact
                {
                    Name = inv.Company.OrganisationName,
                    //ContactNumber = "MM" + inv.Company.CompanyId.ToString(),
                    FirstName = person.FirstName,
                    LastName = person.LastName,
                    EmailAddress = person.Email,
                    Phones = new List<Phone>()
                    {
                        new Phone {PhoneNumber = person.Telephone, PhoneType = PhoneType.Default},
                        new Phone {PhoneNumber = person.Mobile, PhoneType = PhoneType.Mobile}
                    },
                    Addresses = new List<Address>
                    { new Address
                        {
                        //AttentionTo = inv.Company.People.FirstOrDefault(p => p.IsAccountContact) == null 
                        //? inv.Company.People.FirstOrDefault(p=> p.IsPrimaryContact).FullName
                        //: inv.Company.People.FirstOrDefault(p => p.IsAccountContact).FullName,
                            //AddressLine1 = inv.Company.OrganisationName,
                            AddressLine1 = inv.Company.Address.Address1,
                            AddressLine2 = inv.Company.Address.Address2 ?? "",
                            AddressLine3 = inv.Company.Address.Address3 ?? "",
                            Region = inv.Company.Address.CountyState,
                            City = inv.Company.Address.TownCity,
                            PostalCode = inv.Company.Address.PostCode,
                        }
                    }
                },
                AmountDue = (decimal)inv.TotalAmount,
                Date = inv.InvoiceDate,
                DueDate = inv.DueDate,
                LineItems = items,
                LineAmountTypes = LineAmountType.Exclusive
            };
            if (SessionContext.TransferContactDetailsToXero == false)
            {
                ninv.Contact = new Contact
                {
                    Id = inv.Company.XeroId ?? Guid.Empty,
                    Name = inv.Company.OrganisationName
                };
            }
            xinvs.Add(ninv);
        }
        var success = true;
        var xinvresult = new List<Invoice>();
        try
        {
            api.SummarizeErrors(false);
            xinvresult = api.Invoices.Create(xinvs).ToList();
        }
        catch (ValidationException ex)
        {
              // Something's gone wrong
        }
        foreach (var inv in xinvresult)
        {
            var mminvoice = invoices.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ClientInvoiceId == inv.Number);
            if (inv.Errors != null && inv.Errors.Count > 0)
            {
                success = false;
                if (mminvoice != null)
                {
                    var errors = new List<XeroError>();
                    foreach (var err in inv.Errors)
                    {
                        errors.Add(new XeroError { ErrorDescription = err.Message });
                    }
                    mminvoice.XeroErrors = errors;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                mminvoice.XeroTransferDate = DateTime.Now;
                mminvoice.XeroId = inv.Id;
                mminvoice.XeroErrors = new List<XeroError>();
            }
        }
        return new XeroTransferResult
        {
            Invoices = invoices,
            Success = success
        };
    }
```